# Redux - Is the state that is returned by mapStateToProps a copy of the store state?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have this function:

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state){
    return {
        products: state.products
    }
};
```

and the store is like this:

```
var store = {
    products: [1,2,3]
};
```

When I use this.props.products in the connected component, do I still need to do this:

```
var products = this.props.products.slice();
```

to make a copy, or is is already a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For normal use cases (as in, you use the simple `connect()` function from `react-redux` and not the more customizable `connectAdvanced()`), the props delivered to your component are the exact same as what you return in `mapStateToProps`.

Since `mapStateToProps`'s state argument is a direct reference to the store's state, they refer to the actual state of the Redux store.

As such, when you want to modify the props, you'll first need to do a copy of them.
If you do a shallow copy, note that **deeper nested properties** still refer to their counterparts in the store, so be careful not to mutate them!